# ui-router changes to inherited object parameter not persisted to sibling state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to set up some states as follows

```
state('search', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/search.html',
  controller: 'SearchController'
}).
state('check', {
  controller: 'CheckController',
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
  params: {
    subject: null
  }
}).
state('check.status', {
  templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/check-status.client.view.html'
}).
state('check.personal', {
  templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/check-personal.client.view.html'
});
```

Search results are passed into the 'check' state with parameterised `ui-sref`'s.

Within each child state of 'check' I want to change some properties on `subject` and then call `$state.go` (preferably without passing `subject` as a parameter) to move along to the next state in the journey.

I'm finding though that

- `CheckController` is reloaded if the parameter is not supplied on `$state.go` to subsequent states or if I supply it but change it slightly.
- If `CheckController` is reloaded, changes made to the `subject` object aren't persisted through the transition as if `$stateParams` contains a copy of the `subject` object taken at some point earlier by ui-router.

Is there a way to prevent / control either of these behaviours?

Edit:

I found this pattern works out:

```
state('check.status', {
    templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/check-status.client.view.html',
    params: {
        subject: null
    },
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.$parent.subject = $stateParams.subject;
    }
}).
```

Removing the param from the abstract parent, adding it to the first state in the journey and assigning the property on the parent scope with a small controller.

Comment: use resolve block for persist data...

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your config for your child states you can tell ui-router to prevent reloading with this:

```
state('check.status', {
  templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/check-status.client.view.html',
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work - I think only applies to URL parameters.